# Moving Ubuntu to new server

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I have an old Dell Precision 390 desktop with Ubuntu 10.04 that stopped booting because of "a thermal event". I cleaned it, reset the logs but it still won't boot. Not sure what my options are, but if I have to replace the machine, I am not really sure how to copy over my configurations - Jenkins, Postgres, MySQL, Java, Grails, etc. I thought I would move the hd over, but I doubt that would work.

The searches I have found indicate a backup copy (which I stupidly never did since it was "just a dev box"), or just doing a copy from the old to new hd. But since I can't boot this machine anymore, I can't do that.  Is it possible to just remove the hd and put it in a new computer?

Comment: "I thought I would move the hd over, but I doubt that would work"  oh yes it does.

Comment: It is really so simple as just taking the hd out of one, and putting it in another and everything works?

Answer (score 0):

As @Rinzwind suggested in his comment, moving the hard drive between machines will work, and sounds like your best option.  The only issue you might run into is that the name of your network interface may change (from eth0 to eth1, for example).

This change in network interface naming is caused by udev detecting an adapter with a different MAC address, and so giving it the next available name to allow you to have a persistent name-to-hardware mapping.

Udev keeps this configuration in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`.  You can modify the name given to a MAC address there, or you can remove the un-commented lines and let udev re-learn the settings.  Either way you should reboot once you've changed the configuration settings.

I would recommend letting udev regenerate the file because that way it will definitely be done right.